# How to make some categories more important than others in spacy's text classification

Tags: python, categories, spacy, text-classification

I am working on news classification project and I use `spaCy` for this. I have 21 different news categories like `Politics`, `Economy`, `Sport`, `Real estates`, etc. But some categories are more important than others. For example, if an article is related to both `Economy` and `Real estates`, I want the classifier to show `Economy` with more confidence. Can I show it to my model somehow, and if yes, how?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This sounds like a weighting issue. Either weight your inputs and retrain or just weight the targets and sort post-prediction.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy But how do I do that in `spacy`?